# Routing set of users/devices through a specific WAN with a Dual WAN router

Tags: routing, router, wide-area-network, isp

I have two internet connections and I want certain devices/users to always to go through the specific connection while the others would be able to use either WAN in a typical load balancing setup. The point is that one WAN has a monthly cap and the devices forced to use that WAN should not have any internet once that monthly cap is reached.

I believe a Dual WAN router is the only device capable of getting me close to this functionality. So, I'm looking at this [TP-Link](http://www.tp-link.com/Resources/document/TL-R480T_v5_User_Guide.pdf).

I thought I could achieve this through static routing, but I don't see any way to apply the policy based on the source MAC or IP Addr. Is this not possible even with a Dual WAN router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you are looking for is "policy based routing" (PBR), so you have to find a router that support it.

Product recommendation is off-topic here, but among the various options, you can use a free network OS like [VyOs](http://www.vyos.net)

It runs on any x64 platform.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. PBR looks to be what I need.

Out of curiosity, if I were to use a network OS, I'd have to build a box (maybe with a RPi), with multiple NICs to achieve this... is that correct? Or can the os route through the WANs (which have their own routers) if they are connected to the same switch as the PC is connected to?

Comment: you could use a machine with a single physical interface and use VLANs. Of course this would split bandwidth. But PCI-X NIC are very cheap (around 10€).